# Вывод двух одинаковых компонентов

Tags: reactjs

Пытаюсь вывести на экран два компонента следующим образом. Каждый из них должен выводить список файлов в зависимости от того, какой задан `parentId`, но на экран выводятся 2 одинаковых блока. Как решить данный вопрос?

```
class FilesListWrapper extends React.Component {

        componentWillMount() {
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="file-wrapper">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <FilesList key={0} keyPrifix="0" parentId={2}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-6">
                            <FilesList key={1} keyPrifix="1" parentId={0}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

**Код FilesList**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Loader from 'react-loader-spinner';

import { getFiles } from '../../store/files/actions';
import File from "../file/File"

class FilesList extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {

        console.log(this.props.parentId);

        this.props.getFiles(this.props.parentId);
    }

    render() {

        if(typeof this.props.files == "undefined") {
            var files = [];
        } else {
            files = this.props.files;
        }

        return ( <ul className={"files-list files-"+this.props.keyPrifix} key = {this.props.keyPrifix}>
                {
                    files.map((file, index)=> {

                        return <File file={file} key={this.props.keyPrifix+file.id} keyPrifix={this.props.keyPrifix} />
                    })
                }
                </ul>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        files: state.files.files,
        fetchingFiless: state.files.fetchingFiless,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps =  {
    getFiles
};



export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FilesList);
```

Comment: а в компоненте `FilesList` что?

Answer (score 0):

У вас не правильно построена архитектура.

В методе `getFiles` вы устанавливаете в глобальный стейт(store) данные по ключу `files`. Вы запрашиваете данные для каждого компонента отдельно, но ключ один и какой запрос обработается последним, тот и отобразится в обоих компонентах.

Правильнее было бы запрашивать, единожды, все данные в родительском компоненте `<FilesListWrapper />`, сохранять их в глобальный стейт(store) и передавать дочерним компонентам `<FilesList />` конкретные части этого стора.